# Mixed_messages syuzhet package on a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to use the `mixed_messages` function from the `syuzhet` package.

How do I apply this to every row in my data frame?

```
Df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  text = c(
    "hi how are you",
    "this was hell",
    "i don't like it",
    "this was fun for the kids but i didnt like it",
    "this was crazy fun",
    "what a blast"
  )
)
```

Comment: Please provide usable sample data *using `dput(x)`*, I don't think it's safe to assume we'll spend time making that when you yourself won't (especially showing no code or research).

Comment: The [introduction vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/syuzhet/vignettes/syuzhet-vignette.html) suggests `lapply(sample_sents, mixed_messages)`, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(syuzhet)

Df %>% 
dplyr::select(-id) %>% 
apply(1,mixed_messages)
```

Output

```
               [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
entropy           0    0    0    0 1.00    0
metric_entropy    0    0    0    0 0.25    0
```

You can also put this back into your original dataframe.

```
new <-
  Df %>%
  dplyr::select(-id) %>%
  apply(1, mixed_messages) %>%
  as.data.frame()  %>%
  t()

new <- cbind(Df,  new)
row.names(new) <- NULL
```